# todonotes package - how to underline a single word instead of the complete line?

Tags: todonotes

The todonotes package typically underlines the whole line. I would like to have more control over this. Is there an easy way?

For instance, how do I write a todo that underlines just the word 'first' in the second paragraph?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}
    \todo{note 1. full line}
     First paragraph. This is the first sentence of the first paragraph.

     Second paragraph. This is the \todo{note 2. single word} first sentence of the second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

At the moment, the second note underlines from 'first' to the end of the line.

[image]

Using `\todo[noline]{note 2. single word}` results in:

[image]

and the word in not underlined at all.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, not including _anything_ in between that isn't necessary to reproduce the undesired behavior; that’ll clarify what you mean. I think you’re mistaking the line that points to the place within the line of text where the todo note was placed as underlining. Try `\todo[noline]{bla}` as a contrast. And have a look at the [`todonotes` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/todonotes), which is pretty user-friendly.

Comment: It does not really underline the whole line. Rather it draws a connecting line from the insertion point to the todo box. You can eliminate that line with `\todo[noline]{Note Text}`, and then do the underline of the word yourself.

Comment: Oh! I see. So there is no way of "marking" what the note is referring to?

Comment: The note is referring to a point, not to a word. So you will have to indicate that word yourself. See my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Added a macro to do highlighting and the note together, with both disabled when the `disable` option is given to `todonotes`.**

This solution comes from section 1.8.13 of the `todonotes` documentation, but is slightly improved (doesn't eat the following space).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{soul}

\makeatletter
 \if@todonotes@disabled
 \newcommand{\hlnote}[2]{#1}
 \else
 \newcommand{\hlnote}[2]{\todo{#2}\texthl{#1}}
 \fi
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
    \todo{note 1. full line}
     First paragraph. This is the first sentence of the first paragraph.

     Second paragraph. This is the \hlnote{first}{note 2. single word} sentence of the second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that later when I disable the todo notes, I will have to go through the document removing `\ul` commands.

Comment: Maybe there is another package that handle these cases in a better way?

Comment: Well, make your own macro that does the `\ul` and the `\todo` together. Than later redefine that macro to do nothing.

Comment: I will do that but finding a package that does this and in addition leaves a lines between the word and the box with the note would be nice.

Comment: OK, I have adapted the example to include a macro that is conditional on the `disable` option.

Comment: Wait a minute, what does "leaves a lines (sic!) between the word and the box" mean? Isn't that what `\todo` does by default?

Comment: sorry for the typo! I meant something like MS comments. Relevant words are highlighted or underlined and there is still a line. I found your macro very useful! thanks! I removed the noline and highlighted the text instead.

Comment: That code is in the `todonotes` documentation. I just that as basis for my answer, but apparently you needed the original one :)

Comment: Perfect! 1.8.13 in the documentation is exactly what I wanted! Maybe you could update your answer to indicate this. Thanks again for your help.